# HttpURLConnection problem in Android Studio while loading an image from internet

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to download the image from URL: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png
and after that I want to display it in image view. but continuously the error in HttpURLConnection is occurring

On clicking of a button(download function is called) it should remove the previous image and load the new image from the url

I have tried using internet on emulator and its working fine. emulator and my pc is connected to internet. I have also asked permissions in AndroidMenifest. but nothing is solving the problem.

```
package com.example.web;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Error","Error encountered");
             }
            return null;
        }


    }
    public void download(View view) {
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView.setImageResource(0);
        ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = imageDownloader.execute("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png").get();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Permissions in AndroidMenifiest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Your code does not seem like it is being executed, as I do not see what calls `download()`. Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash. Note that cleartext traffic (`http` URLs instead of `https`) is blocked by default on Android 9.0+. And please consider using an image-loading library like Glide or Picasso.

Comment: @CommonsWare I already tried using https instead of http. and download is called when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As Per Your Code I write Down New One just Replace it With Existing One**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap> {
    OutputStream output;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        int count;
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();


            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "DownloadedFile" + ts + ".jpg");


            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                int cur = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);

                if (Math.min(cur, 100) > 98) {
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 5 seconds
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d("Failure", "sleeping failure");
                    }
                }

                Log.i("currentProgress", "currentProgress: " + Math.min(cur, 100) + "\n " + cur);

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;


}
public void download(View view) {
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView.setImageResource(0);
    ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = imageDownloader.execute("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png").get();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Comment: getting this error in logcat: Cleartext HTTP traffic to upload.wikimedia.org not permitted

Comment: changed http to https now getting this error: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Comment: add below Line in android Manifest     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: **like below line**

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: try to uninstall app from emulator or device and then go to android studio ->FIle ->invalidate cache and restart
Then after re run app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197739/discussion-between-codeinsidecofee-and-muhammad-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to download Image and store in Your Local Storage then Use Below Code.**

Here I create One **DownloadFileFromURL.class** File which is my AsyncTask So downloading processed Without Interruption.

```
   public DownloadFileFromURL(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    Log.e(TAG, "onPreExecute: Download started");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();


        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                8192);

        // Output stream
        output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "Your Folder Name" + ts + ".jpg");


        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            int cur = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);

            if (Math.min(cur, 100) > 98) {
                try {
                    // Sleep for 5 seconds
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d("Failure", "sleeping failure");
                }
            }

            Log.i("currentProgress", "currentProgress: " + Math.min(cur, 100) + "\n " + cur);

            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Now Call Above File in Your Activity or When You want. At the time of Calling this AsyncTask pass Your URLto download images.**

```
new DownloadFileFromURL(context).execute("Your Download URL");
```

Comment: Thanks. but can u please fix my existing code? I'm not willing to add something new which I don't understand.

Comment: Ok i Will Update You Soon.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I'm waiting

Comment: Your Welcome Check it might be need minor changes Because i can't run it becasue i dont have your xml file.